# Initialisation of HDD fails (I/O Error, Western Digital)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have a new HDD which I bought from Amazon Warehousedeals.
At the moment it isn't running. Someone else did a video of this problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVDRelP8OOU

- If haven't plugged any jumper to the hdd
- It is recognised in bios
- Bios-Firmware is up to date
- I restarted my computer

Results from WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostics:

> Test Option: QUICK TEST 
>   Model Number: WDC WD20EZRX-00DC0B0 
>   Unit Serial Number: WD-WCC300748118 
>   Firmware Number: 80.00A80 
>   Capacity: 2000.40 GB 
>   SMART Status: PASS 
>   Test Result: PASS 
>   Test Time: 14:05:18, June 21, 2015

Result from Chrystal-Tool:
[image: ChrystalScreenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: post a picture of this tool: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html

Comment: @magicandre1981: I added the screenshot.

Comment: the WD drive seams to be ok, but drive E: has issues. Can you please add a picture of it?

Comment: Try to switch the SATA port and cable. If there is no change test it in a different system. If it still gives the I/O error check the warranty here http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=Bn2mHO . If it's still valid contact the support team so they can arrange a replacement http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=qsHtkb .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution which worked for me:

I contacted WD-Support. The support is very good and it tells you exactly what you have to do. After they recognized my HDD has too much bad sectors they offered me a RMA. I send the HDD back to Amazon and ordered a new one.

Thanks for your help.